# filesize function is crashing the Apache server

Tags: php, windows, apache, segmentation-fault

On using filesize is PHP is crashing the apache server.

No error is seen in the log file but window event viewer shows

> Faulting application `Apache.exe`, version 2.0.63.200, faulting module `php_iisfunc.dll`, version 5.2.7.7, fault address `0x00001085`.

Answer (score 0):

Why is the `php_iisfunc` module activated in the first place?

Can you try deactivating it in your `php.ini`?